# Is there a way to view the "TV Edits" of movies without waiting for them to come on TV?

Tags: distribution

When *Dumb & Dumber* came on TBS, I pulled my eight year old on the couch and said "Here..let's watch this."

The laughs started when Jeff Daniels walked out in the dog suit and didn't stop till the credits rolled.

It was a fun, bonding moment.

When it came on Stars a few weeks later, we decided to watch it again.

This time, we saw scenes I had forgotten about; particularly Seabass and the bathroom.

Very funny and nothing overt; but a theme I would have waited a few years to show my son.

So, with that being said, is there a way to obtain a TV edit of a movie without waiting for it to actually come on TV?

I'm guessing DVDs are out the question; but are there any online services that would offer this?  (e.g. if there was a TBS on demand that showed the edited Dumb & Dumber movie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to answers on a similar question on ask.com, you have several options:

Check your local video store - they sometimes carry edited versions (especially Blockbuster),

Contact the production company directly to find out if they have edited films available,

Purchase a 'ClearPlay' DVD play that edits out offensive material as the film is played.

It's worth noting this warning:

*Do not purchase copies of movies from companies that buy films and then edit them themselves. These companies operate in violation of current copyright law. ClearPlay doesn't violate copyright law because the technology doesn't alter the original version of the film and create a new one, according to Clean Edited Movies.*

Comment: For us, there is no such thing as "local video store"; sign o' the times.  The Clearplay looks interesting.  ty.